# Проверить значение в двухмерном массиве и вернуть ключ

Tags: javascript

Привет!

Ко мне на страницу приходит переменная через localStorage со значением например "Разработка сайтов".

И у меня есть массив

```
db[0][{'page_title':'Разработка сайтов','id':'92'}]
db[1][{'page_title':'Мобильные приложения','id':'94'}]
db[2][{'page_title':'Дизайн','id':'96'}]
db[3][{'page_title':'ИТ-инфраструктура','id':'98'}]
```

Мне нужно найти в этом массиве значение "Разработка сайтов", и вернуть ключ.
Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать?

И кстати, было бы хорошо вернуть false, если не найдено.

И ещё, можно решить проблему, если бы я знал как c помощью push добавить в массив таким образом:

```
db['Разработка сайтов'][{'page_title':'Разработка сайтов','id':'92'}]
db['Мобильные приложения'][{'page_title':'Мобильные приложения','id':'94'}]
db['Дизайн'][{'page_title':'Дизайн','id':'96'}]
db['ИТ-инфраструктура'][{'page_title':'ИТ-инфраструктура','id':'98'}]
```

Спасибо

Comment: что будет, если я вам скажу, что вы должны использовать не массивы, а обычные хэши:

    {
        'Разработка сайтов':{'page_title':'Разработка сайтов','id':'92'},
        'Мобильные приложения':{'page_title':'Мобильные приложения','id':'94'},
        'Дизайн':{'page_title':'Дизайн','id':'96'},
        'ИТ-инфраструктура':{'page_title':'ИТ-инфраструктура','id':'98'}
    }

тогда доступ будет предельно прост:

    obj['Разработка сайтов'];// вернёт объект {'page_title':'Разработка сайтов','id':'92'}

да, и `hasOwnProperty('Акваланг')` вернёт `false`, как вам и надо

Answer (score 1):

Например так можно сделать

```
function find(arr, value) {
    for (i in arr) for (j in arr[i]) if (arr[i][j]== value) return [i, j];
    return false;
}; 
arr=[{'x':5, 'y':6, 'z':7}, {'b':8, 'c':9}];
alert(find(arr, 9));
```

Возвращает массив ключей

```
[1, 'c']
```

Если под ключом Вы подразумеваете 'id', то его можно получить так

```
arr[find(arr, 'строка поиска')[0]]['id']
```

Comment: debagger пишет: 

Bad for in variable 'i'
Bad for in variable 'j'

И скрипт не работает.

Comment: Странно. Я проверял прежде, чем постить в опера мобайл.